# How to print to console in color?

Tags: python, ubuntu

How to print in color using python print. For example

```
print('This should be red')
print('This should be green')
```

Now everything is white text on black background. I use ubuntu, if it helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672876/colored-console-output-in-linux

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Define color like this:

```
W  = '\033[0m'  # white (normal)
R  = '\033[31m' # red
G  = '\033[32m' # green
O  = '\033[33m' # orange
B  = '\033[34m' # blue
P  = '\033[35m' # purple

print(R+"hello how are you"+W)
```

Demo:
[image: Demo]

see all color codes here:[Color Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)

Comment: On windows you could also need the `colorama` package (see the questions that this one duplicates).

Comment: This solution unfortunately doesn't work in Anaconda prompt

Answer (score 5):

Below is a handy function I find useful. It will print the text you provide in the desired foreground and background colors you specify using standard RGB tuples so you do not have to remember ANSI codes. To find the RGB values you may want to use you can use the color picker at  https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp.

```
def print_in_color(txt_msg,fore_tupple,back_tupple,):
    #prints the text_msg in the foreground color specified by fore_tupple with the background specified by back_tupple 
    #text_msg is the text, fore_tupple is foregroud color tupple (r,g,b), back_tupple is background tupple (r,g,b)
    rf,gf,bf=fore_tupple
    rb,gb,bb=back_tupple
    msg='{0}' + txt_msg
    mat='\33[38;2;' + str(rf) +';' + str(gf) + ';' + str(bf) + ';48;2;' + str(rb) + ';' +str(gb) + ';' + str(bb) +'m' 
    print(msg .format(mat))
    print('\33[0m') # returns default print color to back to black

# example of use using a message with variables
fore_color='cyan'
back_color='dark green'
msg='foreground color is {0} and the background color is {1}'.format(fore_color, back_color)
print_in_color(msg, (0,255,255),(0,127,127))
```

Comment: should be "rf,gf,bf=fore_tupple"      not     "rf,bf,gf=fore_tupple"

Comment: @GerryP This is absolutely wonderful, thank you.

Comment: Great method 
Using a single `print` to print the message and return to the default black print color allows to avoid blank lines: `print(msg .format(mat) + '\33[0m' )`

Answer (score 4):

Use the colored module.

```py
import colored
color = colored.fg(196) #orange
print(color + "This text is orange")
```

https://pypi.org/project/colored/

Answer (score 1):

Using a module such as `colorconsole` is easier:

```sh
pip install colorconsole
```

Then e.g.

```py
from colorconsole import terminal

screen = terminal.get_terminal(conEmu=False)

screen.cprint(4, 0, "This is red\n")
screen.cprint(10, 0, "This is light green\n")
screen.cprint(0, 11, "This is black on light cyan\n")

screen.reset_colors()
```

It also supports 256/24 bit colours if available.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Function here: It has the colors: red, blue, green

```
colors = {'red':'\033[31m', 'blue':'\033[34m', 'green':'\033[32m'}

def colorprint(string, text_color = 'default', bold = False, underline = False):
    if underline == True:
            string = '\033[4m' + string
    if bold == True:
            string = '\033[1m' + string
    if text_color == 'default' or text_color in colors:
            for color in colors:
                    if text_color == color:
                            string = colors[color] + string
    else:
            raise ValueError ("Colors not in:", colors.keys())

    print(string + '\033[0m')
```