# How do I print colored output with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, colors

I have a simple print statement:

```
print('hello friends')
```

I would like the output to be blue in the terminal. How can I accomplish this with Python3?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is right now.

Comment: You can use [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51708889/8584198) classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in terminal with colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print colored output to the terminal in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340049/how-do-i-print-colored-output-to-the-terminal-in-python)

Answer (score 55):

It is very simple with [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama), just do this:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style
print(Fore.BLUE + "Hello World")
```

And here is the running result in Python3 REPL:

[image]

And call this to reset the color settings:

```
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
```

To avoid printing an empty line write this:

```
print(f"{Fore.BLUE}Hello World{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```

Comment: As the original creator of Colorama, let me caution: If you're writing a quick throwaway script, the usage shown above is fine. But if compatibility with old Windows "CMD" terminals is not your primary concern, then I'd advise using another amazing color library, such as rich or blessings. These are much more capable, and Colorama has no intention of adding features to mimic them. 1/2

Comment: The intended purpose of Colorama is to ensure ANSI codes, that work out of the box on all unix-like computers, also work on old Windows CMD terminals. Nowadays, modern Windows terminals also handle ANSI characters properly, so this concern is growing redundant. Unfortunately, I forgot to "do one thing well", and added to Colorama the convenience constants like "Fore.BLUE" above. Now users want to add more constants and functions, for extra ANSI functionality such as moving the cursor, etc. While I have succumbed to some of those requests, in general Colorama does not intend to support them 2/3

Comment: If you want to do increasingly fancy things with ANSI codes, such as moving the cursor, clearing the terminal, etc, then just use rich or blessings, which are intended to support this.

(Note this means it is valid that a few corner-case apps might want to use *both* (rich or blessings or ???) to generate ANSI codes, *plus* colorama to convert those codes to work on old Windows terminals. But your app is probably not one of them. Just use rich. Or blessings.)

Answer (score 31):

Here's a class of mine I use to color specific output in Python 3 scripts. You could import the class and use like so:
`from colorprint import ColorPrint as _
_.print_fail('Error occurred, quitting program')`

```
import sys

# Colored printing functions for strings that use universal ANSI escape sequences.
# fail: bold red, pass: bold green, warn: bold yellow, 
# info: bold blue, bold: bold white

class ColorPrint:

    @staticmethod
    def print_fail(message, end = '\n'):
        sys.stderr.write('\x1b[1;31m' + message.strip() + '\x1b[0m' + end)

    @staticmethod
    def print_pass(message, end = '\n'):
        sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1;32m' + message.strip() + '\x1b[0m' + end)

    @staticmethod
    def print_warn(message, end = '\n'):
        sys.stderr.write('\x1b[1;33m' + message.strip() + '\x1b[0m' + end)

    @staticmethod
    def print_info(message, end = '\n'):
        sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1;34m' + message.strip() + '\x1b[0m' + end)

    @staticmethod
    def print_bold(message, end = '\n'):
        sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1;37m' + message.strip() + '\x1b[0m' + end)
```

Answer (score 29):

Put these classes into **Color.py** file near your **test.py** file and run **test.py**.
I've tested these classes on Ubuntu Server 16.04 and Linux Mint 18.2 . All classes worked very good except GColor (**RGB**), that, it is usable in graphical terminal like Linux Mint terminal.
Also, you can use these classes like this:

```
print(Formatting.Italic + ANSI_Compatible.Color(12) + "This is a " + Formatting.Bold + "test" + Formatting.Reset_Bold +  "!" + ANSI_Compatible.END + Formatting.Reset)
print(Color.B_DarkGray + Color.F_LightBlue + "This is a " + Formatting.Bold + "test" + Formatting.Reset_Bold +  "!" + Base.END)
```

Result:

[image]

***Note: It's not working on Windows!***

File **Color.py** :

```
class Base:
    # Foreground:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    # Formatting
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'    
    # End colored text
    END = '\033[0m'
    NC ='\x1b[0m' # No Color

class ANSI_Compatible:
    END = '\x1b[0m'
    # If Foreground is False that means color effect on Background
    def Color(ColorNo, Foreground=True): # 0 - 255
        FB_G = 38 # Effect on foreground
        if Foreground != True:
            FB_G = 48 # Effect on background
        return '\x1b[' + str(FB_G) + ';5;' + str(ColorNo) + 'm'

class Formatting:
    Bold = "\x1b[1m"
    Dim = "\x1b[2m"
    Italic = "\x1b[3m"
    Underlined = "\x1b[4m"
    Blink = "\x1b[5m"
    Reverse = "\x1b[7m"
    Hidden = "\x1b[8m"
    # Reset part
    Reset = "\x1b[0m"
    Reset_Bold = "\x1b[21m"
    Reset_Dim = "\x1b[22m"
    Reset_Italic = "\x1b[23m"
    Reset_Underlined = "\x1b[24"
    Reset_Blink = "\x1b[25m"
    Reset_Reverse = "\x1b[27m"
    Reset_Hidden = "\x1b[28m"

class GColor: # Gnome supported
    END = "\x1b[0m"
    # If Foreground is False that means color effect on Background
    def RGB(R, G, B, Foreground=True): # R: 0-255  ,  G: 0-255  ,  B: 0-255
        FB_G = 38 # Effect on foreground
        if Foreground != True:
            FB_G = 48 # Effect on background
        return "\x1b[" + str(FB_G) + ";2;" + str(R) + ";" + str(G) + ";" + str(B) + "m"

class Color:
    # Foreground
    F_Default = "\x1b[39m"
    F_Black = "\x1b[30m"
    F_Red = "\x1b[31m"
    F_Green = "\x1b[32m"
    F_Yellow = "\x1b[33m"
    F_Blue = "\x1b[34m"
    F_Magenta = "\x1b[35m"
    F_Cyan = "\x1b[36m"
    F_LightGray = "\x1b[37m"
    F_DarkGray = "\x1b[90m"
    F_LightRed = "\x1b[91m"
    F_LightGreen = "\x1b[92m"
    F_LightYellow = "\x1b[93m"
    F_LightBlue = "\x1b[94m"
    F_LightMagenta = "\x1b[95m"
    F_LightCyan = "\x1b[96m"
    F_White = "\x1b[97m"
    # Background
    B_Default = "\x1b[49m"
    B_Black = "\x1b[40m"
    B_Red = "\x1b[41m"
    B_Green = "\x1b[42m"
    B_Yellow = "\x1b[43m"
    B_Blue = "\x1b[44m"
    B_Magenta = "\x1b[45m"
    B_Cyan = "\x1b[46m"
    B_LightGray = "\x1b[47m"
    B_DarkGray = "\x1b[100m"
    B_LightRed = "\x1b[101m"
    B_LightGreen = "\x1b[102m"
    B_LightYellow = "\x1b[103m"
    B_LightBlue = "\x1b[104m"
    B_LightMagenta = "\x1b[105m"
    B_LightCyan = "\x1b[106m"
    B_White = "\x1b[107m"
```

And,

File **test.py**:

```
from Color import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Base:")
    print(Base.FAIL,"This is a test!", Base.END)

    print("ANSI_Compatible:")
    print(ANSI_Compatible.Color(120),"This is a test!", ANSI_Compatible.END)

    print("Formatting:")
    print(Formatting.Bold,"This is a test!", Formatting.Reset)

    print("GColor:") # Gnome terminal supported
    print(GColor.RGB(204,100,145),"This is a test!", GColor.END)

    print("Color:")
    print(Color.F_Cyan,"This is a test!",Color.F_Default)
```

Result:

On Ubuntu Server 16.04

[image: Result on Ubuntu Server 16.04]

On Linux Mint 18.2

[image: Result on Linux Mint 18.2]

Comment: A useful and basic and maybe complete answer from a good Linux developer.

Comment: This is not an efficient answer. Please minimize the code to only what's needed.

Comment: Huge fan of the code exactly as is.  Provides the answers I was looking for and then some.

Comment: The formatting tags do not work on win10, they provide color markings.

Answer (score 18):

Since Python is interpreted and run in C, it is possible to set colors without a module.

You can define a class for colors like this:

```
class color:
   PURPLE = '\033[1;35;48m'
   CYAN = '\033[1;36;48m'
   BOLD = '\033[1;37;48m'
   BLUE = '\033[1;34;48m'
   GREEN = '\033[1;32;48m'
   YELLOW = '\033[1;33;48m'
   RED = '\033[1;31;48m'
   BLACK = '\033[1;30;48m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4;37;48m'
   END = '\033[1;37;0m'
```

When writing code, you can simply write:

print(color.BLUE + "hello friends" + color.END)

Note that the color you choose will have to be capitalized like your class definition, and that these are color choices that I personally find satisfying.  For a fuller array of color choices and, indeed, background choices as well, please see: https://gist.github.com/RabaDabaDoba/145049536f815903c79944599c6f952a.

This is code for C, but can easily be adapted to Python once you realize how the code is written.

Take BLUE for example, since that is what you are wanting to display.

```
BLUE = '033[1;37;48m'
```

\033 tells Python to break and pay attention to the following formatting.

1 informs the code to be bold.  (I prefer 1 to 0 because it pops more.)

34 is the actual color code.  It chooses blue.

48m is the background color.  48m is the same shade as the console window, so it seems there is no background.

Comment: This works in my IDE but when I run my program via the commandline then it does not. instead a left-arrow gets printed to the terminal.

Comment: I assume you're trying to get them to work on Windows.

These color codes and Windows have a well-known and unhappy working relationship.  I wish that there were a way to get the color on Windows without downloading or importing any additional modules, but the only way I know how to get these codes to work is by using the colorama module.

You'll have to download the module [link](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/#files), and install it.  Once you've done that, two lines at the top of your code should get it working, even on Windows:

import colorama
colorama.init()

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would go with `print("{} hello friends {}".format(color.BLUE, color.END))` as it's simply more readable.

Answer (score 12):

```
# Pure Python 3.x demo, 256 colors
# Works with bash under Linux and MacOS

fg = lambda text, color: "\33[38;5;" + str(color) + "m" + text + "\33[0m"
bg = lambda text, color: "\33[48;5;" + str(color) + "m" + text + "\33[0m"

def print_six(row, format):
    for col in range(6):
        color = row*6 + col + 4
        if color>=0:
            text = "{:3d}".format(color)
            print (format(text,color), end=" ")
        else:
            print("   ", end=" ")

for row in range(-1,42):
    print_six(row, fg)
    print("",end=" ")
    print_six(row, bg)
    print()

# Simple usage: print(fg("text", 160))
```

[image: Text with altering foreground and background, colors 0..141]
[image: Text with altering foreground and background, colors 142..255]

Comment: Only `7`, `30–47` and `90–107` get coloured in Pycharm. 4 gets an underline, and 41 is pink. The two columns are identical, meaning `30–39` and `90–99` have a foreground colour, whilst `40–47` and `100–107` have background colours.

Comment: Or in one line: for i in range(256): print ('\33[38;5;'+str(i)+'m text ' + str(i) +' \33[0m')

Comment: @user1438233, nice. But what I wanted to show is the period of six. Because color 166 "logically" follows color 160, and so on, while neighbouring colors like 165 and 166 could look quite different. So this demo just reveals the "structure".

Answer (score 8):

Try this way, without import modules, just use colors code numbers, defined as constants:

```
BLUE = '34m'
message = 'hello friends'


def display_colored_text(color, text):
    colored_text = f"\033[{color}{text}\033[00m"
    return colored_text
```

Example:

```
>>> print(display_colored_text(BLUE, message))
hello friends
```

Answer (score 7):

To use colour in the console see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786287/6683985) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12493201/6683985).

There are modules dedicated to this task such as [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) and [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)

Answer (score 6):

I use the [colors](https://github.com/verigak/colors/) module. Clone the git repository, run the `setup.py` and you're good.  You can then print text with colors very easily like this:

```
import colors
print(colors.red('this is red'))
print(colors.green('this is green'))
```

This works on the command line, but might need further configuration for IDLE.

Answer (score 4):

This one answer I have got from the earlier python2 answers that is

1. Install [termcolor](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/) module.

   `pip3 install termcolor`
2. Import the `colored` class from termcolor.

   `from termcolor import colored`
3. Use the provided methods, below is an example.

   `print(colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green'))`

Comment: When I do that I get some interesting printout `ESC[31mhelloESC[0m ESC[32mworldESC[0m`

Comment: thats actually control function for coded character set, which works by default in common linux shells but in windows you have to enable virtual terminals to do that.
@MoreInfo  [ECMA Standard for Control Functions](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf)

Comment: Windows Virtual Terminal:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

Answer (score 3):

### For lazy people:

Without installing any additional library, it is compatible with every single terminal i know.

**Class approach:**

First do `import config as cfg`.

`clipped` is dataframe.

```
            #### HEADER: ####
            print('{0:<23} {1:>24} {2:>26} {3:>26} {4:>11} {5:>11}'.format('Road name','Classification','Function','Form of road','Length','Distance') )

            #### Now row by row: ####
            for index, row in clipped.iterrows():
                rdName      = self.colorize(row['name1'],cfg.Green)
                rdClass     = self.colorize(row['roadClassification'],cfg.LightYellow)
                rdFunction  = self.colorize(row['roadFunction'],cfg.Yellow)
                rdForm      = self.colorize(row['formOfWay'],cfg.LightBlue)
                rdLength    = self.colorize(row['length'],cfg.White)
                rdDistance  = self.colorize(row['distance'],cfg.LightCyan)
                print('{0:<30} {1:>35} {2:>35} {3:>35} {4:>20} {5:>20}'.format(rdName,rdClass,rdFunction,rdForm,rdLength,rdDistance) )
```

**Meaning of `{0:<30} {1:>35} {2:>35} {3:>35} {4:>20} {5:>20}`:**

`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` -> columns, there are 6 in total in this case

`30, 35, 20` -> width of column (note that you'll have to add length of `\033[96m` - this for Python is a string as well), just experiment :)

`>, <` -> justify: right, left (there is `=` for filling with zeros as well)

**What is in `config.py:`**

```
#colors
ResetAll = "\033[0m"

Bold       = "\033[1m"
Dim        = "\033[2m"
Underlined = "\033[4m"
Blink      = "\033[5m"
Reverse    = "\033[7m"
Hidden     = "\033[8m"

ResetBold       = "\033[21m"
ResetDim        = "\033[22m"
ResetUnderlined = "\033[24m"
ResetBlink      = "\033[25m"
ResetReverse    = "\033[27m"
ResetHidden     = "\033[28m"

Default      = "\033[39m"
Black        = "\033[30m"
Red          = "\033[31m"
Green        = "\033[32m"
Yellow       = "\033[33m"
Blue         = "\033[34m"
Magenta      = "\033[35m"
Cyan         = "\033[36m"
LightGray    = "\033[37m"
DarkGray     = "\033[90m"
LightRed     = "\033[91m"
LightGreen   = "\033[92m"
LightYellow  = "\033[93m"
LightBlue    = "\033[94m"
LightMagenta = "\033[95m"
LightCyan    = "\033[96m"
White        = "\033[97m"
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you please explain what self.colorize() is? I cannot find its definition in the pasted code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After installing the [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) package with `pip3 install colorist`, simply type:

```py
from colorist import blue

blue("hello friends")
```

[image]

I'm the author of the [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) package, in full disclosure. Sometimes you may want a little more control over the terminal style, so you can also do this:

```py
from colorist import Color

print(f"Only {Color.BLUE}this part{Color.OFF} is in colour")
```

[image]

As [f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), you can simply use string concatenation with a `+` between strings in earlier versions of Python. The result is the same:

```py
print("Only " + Color.BLUE + "this part" + Color.OFF + " is in colour")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

def colour_print(text,colour):
    if colour == 'OKBLUE':
        string = bcolors.OKBLUE + text + bcolors.ENDC
        print(string)
    elif colour == 'HEADER':
        string = bcolors.HEADER + text + bcolors.ENDC
        print(string)
    elif colour == 'OKCYAN':
        string = bcolors.OKCYAN + text + bcolors.ENDC
        print(string)
    elif colour == 'OKGREEN':
        string = bcolors.OKGREEN + text + bcolors.ENDC
        print(string)
    elif colour == 'WARNING':
        string = bcolors.WARNING + text + bcolors.ENDC
        print(string)
    elif colour == 'FAIL':
        string = bcolors.HEADER + text + bcolors.ENDC
        print(string)
    elif colour == 'BOLD':
        string = bcolors.BOLD + text + bcolors.ENDC
        print(string)
    elif colour == 'UNDERLINE':
        string = bcolors.UNDERLINE + text + bcolors.ENDC
        print(string)
```

just copy the above code.
just call them easily

```
colour_print('Hello world','OKBLUE')
colour_print('easy one','OKCYAN')
colour_print('copy and paste','OKGREEN')
colour_print('done','OKBLUE')
```

Hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

I would like to show you about how to color code. There is also a game to it if you would like to play it down below. Copy and paste if you would like and make sure to have a good day everyone! Also, this is for Python 3, not 2.
( Game )

```
   # The Color Game!
# Thank you for playing this game.
# Hope you enjoy and please do not copy it. Thank you!
```

#

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
score = 0

def Check_Answer(answer):
    if (answer == "no"):
        print('correct')
        return True
    else:
        print('wrong')

answer = input((Fore.RED + "This is green."))
if Check_Answer(answer) == True:
    score = score + 1
else:
    pass

answer = input((Fore.BLACK + "This is red."))
if Check_Answer(answer) == True:
    score = score + 1
else:
    pass

answer = input((Fore.BLUE + "This is black."))

if Check_Answer(answer) == True:
    score = score + 1
else:
    pass

print('Your Score is ', score)
```

Now for the color coding. It also comes with a list of colors YOU can try.

```
# Here is how to color code in Python 3!
# Some featured color codes are : RED, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW, OR WHITE. I don't think purple or pink are not out yet.
# Here is how to do it. (Example is down below!)

import colorama
from colorama import Fore
print(Fore.RED + "This is red..")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Approach 1 -- for alien robots

The simplest, most direct answer appears to be something like:

```py
print('\033[94m' + 'hello friends'  + '\033[0m')
```

This answer is however difficult to suggest because:

- it's written in alien code (what is `'\033[94m'`?? Not good enough for us humans)
- it is locked to one color only, and, in practice, it is often useful to have a palete available on the spot to choose the color that feels right

## Approach 2 -- 3rd-party package approach

Installing something like [`colorama`](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) or [`termcolor`](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/) can be a way to go. However:

- This approach does not apply to every person because there are many situations in which it is not practical to install a package from pypi.

## Approach 3 -- Just put it in a class

Some of the answers here already suggest this approach. Basically, just dump the alien codes (e.g. `\033[95m`,`\033[94m`, `\033[0m`, ...) into the attributes of a class and then build strings using the names of the class attributes. Example:

```py
class Colors:
    OKBLUE='\033[94m'
    ENDC='\033[0m'

print(Colors.OKBLUE + 'hello friends' + Colors.END)
```

This solves the problem and allows adding more alien codes for other colors if needed. In many projects, this approach is good and enough.

However, in some projects, this approach doesn't work well. As we use the `Colors` class over and over again, the whole process of writing string concatenations (using additions or equivalent approaches) becomes a bit problematic in terms of making your code less readable.

## Approach 4 -- Just put it in a metaclass

A nice API could be something like this:

```py
from utils import Colors  # `utils` is a fictional module where we would have our `Colors` class

greeting = Colors.okblue('hello friends')
print(greeting)
# Or even shorter
Colors.print_okblue('hello friends')
```

In this example, the `.okblue(...)` and `.print_okblue(...)` are class methods that provide a shortcut through an automatic conversion of the method names to the respective alien codes. This type of shortcut method can be implemented using something like the `__getattr__` customization.

However, I have tried doing that in the `Colors`  class, but it didn't work well because I would then need to create an instance of the `Colors` class (`colors = Colors()`) in order to use the shortcut methods. Instead, I wanted to keep using these methods as class methods. Therefore, I had to go for a metaclass.

Let's say we have the following `utils.py`:

```py
from functools import partial


class _MetaColors(type):
    
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    B = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    U = '\033[4m'

    _ENDC = '\033[0m'

    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        if name.startswith('print_'):
            key = name.lstrip('print_').upper()
            assert not key.startswith('_'), 'Color key cannot start with `_`'
            return partial(cls.print, key)
        else:
            key = name.upper()
            assert not key.startswith('_'), 'Color key cannot start with `_`'
            return partial(cls.colorize, key)
    
    @classmethod
    def colorize(cls, key, *args):
        ini = getattr(cls, key.upper(), None)
        assert ini != None, f'Color key "{key}" not recognized'
        string = ' '.join(str(a) for a in args)
        return ini + string + cls._ENDC

    @classmethod
    def print(cls, key, *args, **kwds):
        colorized = cls.colorize(key, *args)
        print(colorized, **kwds)


class Colors(metaclass=_MetaColors):
    pass
```

Then, you can just use colors from other modules like this:

```py
from utils import Colors

print(Colors.okblue('hello friends'))
# or
greeting = Colors.okblue('hello friends')
print(greeting)

print('hello', Colors.okblue('friends'))

print(f'hello {Colors.okblue("friends")}')

Colors.print_okblue('hello friends')
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to solutions above, but with a **dict**

```
def c(color):
    
    color_dict = {
        "PURPLE": "\033[95m",
        "CYAN": "\033[96m",
        "DARKCYAN": "\033[36m",
        "BLUE": "\033[94m",
        "GREEN": "\033[92m",
        "YELLOW": "\033[93m",
        "RED": "\033[91m",
        "BOLD": "\033[1m",
        "UNDERLINE": "\033[4m",
        "END": "\033[0m"}
    
    for k, v in color_dict.items():
        k = k.lower()[0:1]
        if k == color :
            return v
```

`print(c("y")+"Hello World")`

Answer (score -3):

For windows just do this:

```
import os
os.system("color 01")
print('hello friends')
```

Where it says "01" that is saying background black, and text color blue. Go into CMD Prompt and type color help for a list of colors.

Comment: That certainly works but converts **ALL THE SCREEN** to that color not just the text you are printing