# How to print text with multiple different types of colors in he same line in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to do some visualizing data on the terminal and I am doing lots of printing to do that. The issue I am having is that certain character symbols look the same. I figured that coloring them differently would help me see the differences. I see from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473297/how-do-i-print-colored-output-with-python-3) that there is a way to do it, but I don't understand what I am looking at. There is no explanation for what is going on in those solutions.

How do you specify, in the same line, text with different colors?
I should also mention that I am building the printable string **OUTSIDE** of the call to `print()`. How do you build the colorful string outside of the `print()` call?

A rewritten form of my question:

```
1. Colorize the text I print to the string with multiple types of colors.
2. Colorize the string BEFORE it gets sent to the "print()" call.
```

A couple examples would be great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There could be multiple ways to achieve this. One which doesn't require any extra packages is to use ANSI color codes. Look at [this link](https://ozzmaker.com/add-colour-to-text-in-python/). Below are some examples.

`s = "\033[1;32;40m Bright Green on black  \033[1;31;43m Red on yellow \033[1;34;42m Blue on green \033[1;37;40m"
print(s)`

Here in first code `\033[1;32;40m`, `\033[` is the escape code followed by `1` for bold, `32` for bright green text and `40` for black background. The 3 codes are separated by `;` and ended with `m`. Adding all the 3 codes (1, 32 and 40 here) isn't mandatory though.

output:
[image]

Other ways to achieve this can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-colors-python-terminal/).

Comment: A side question: How do you get rid of all of the color changes? In other words, I got the color text I want. Now, I want to turn off all of that color stuff. How do you do that?

Comment: Add `\033[0m` to the end of the string which is the code for 'no effect'.

Answer (score 4):

Using [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) just like the answer you linked is doing:

```
from colorama import Fore, Style

my_str = f"{Fore.BLUE}Hello, {Style.RESET_ALL} guys. {Fore.RED} I should be red."

print(my_str)
```

This gives me:

[image: this output]

As you can see `Fore.<color name>` changes the color of the text after it, until the `Style.RESET_ALL`. After that you can change the color of the text again.

Comment: any way to save it as png?