# How to highlight only certain part of matched regex in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, colors

If you do `echo -ne "line1aa\nline2bbb\nline3cc\n" | grep line2 --color=always` you get color highlighted if regex matches..
I want to implement similar in python. The code looks like this

```py
from termcolor import colored
for line in lines:
  if re.search(regex, line)
    print(colored(line, color='red'))
```

but prints the entire line. I want to color only highlighted like
in `aaaabbbbccccddd`, `bbbb` should only be highlighted red. The `bbbb` refers to regex. Here's a picture

[image: color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly simple, first print the prefix to your captured group, print with default color, then print the group with your desired color, and the suffix with default.
Refer to color guide here: [How to print text with multiple different types of colors in he same line in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006808/how-to-print-text-with-multiple-different-types-of-colors-in-he-same-line-in-pyt)

Edit:
To expand on this, in your if statement you can extract the capture group. Not sure how to highlight on phone so apologies for the lack of markup but:
match = re.search().group()
you can then split the string using
values = line.split(match)
this will get you the prefix as the first member of the array (values[0]) and the suffix as the second.

Now, if there is more than 1 regex match, you will get an exception using .group(), and your line will be split into more than 2 values. To handle this, use line.split(match, 1) to only split line in 2 parts (everything after first match will be a suffix) , and group(1) to capture the first occurrence only (you need this for splitting).