# Printing colorful message in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I print `Hello World` in different colors

```
Print("Hello World")
```

I want to print it two times one in red another in blue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print colored output with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473297/how-do-i-print-colored-output-with-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module `termcolor` (install it running `pip install termcolor`). Try this:

```
from termcolor import colored

print(colored("Hello","blue"))
print(colored("Hello","red"))
```