# How to make string appear red in python?

Tags: python

I am just getting started with Python. I have an error string that I want to stood out, currently it is just a basic text like the one you read right now.

```
   error = future.exception() is not None
        string = f'{getTimestamp()}: The "{future.tag}" task '
        string += f'failed: "{future.exception()}"\n' if error else 'was completed.\n'
```

How would it be the best way that string to be displayed in color red?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print colored output with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473297/how-do-i-print-colored-output-with-python-3)

Comment: Displayed In a terminal or in html page?

Comment: I have tried using it , whenever I import the colorama it keeps comming an error..And not allowing me to run the application

Comment: It's executable Python application ..

Comment: Please post your code with colorama and what's the error that you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

try this
using plain python(ANSI codes)

```py
string='your string'
print(f'\033[91m{string}\033[0m')
```

using colorama

```py
from colorama import Fore, Style
string="your string"
print(Fore.RED + string)
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
```

i think this works.