# colored does not work in jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, colors, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python and jupyter-notebook. I am trying to print something with colors and I was thinking of using the `colored` package.

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 and the jupyter-notebook is open in google chrome.

I am trying this by doing:

```
from termcolor import colored

print(colored('hello', 'red'))
print(colored("hello red world", 'red'))
```

I tried to restart the kernel, I tried to restart the whole jupyter-notebook, and I also tried

However, I get the following
[image]

Could you help me in understanding why it does not work?

Comment: you should probably state your operating system and maybe also your shell

Comment: to debug, try if [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246996/1046007) works for you

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will try as soon as I will have access again to the notebook and update here. I added my OS And browser. I don't know what you mean by 'shell'

Answer (score 0):

That is odd. Make sure you the colored lib is installed on your PC. I just ran your code on my notebook it worked out fine.

Comment: actually the OP is not using the `colored` package, but the `termcolor` package (which is not based on `colored`)

Comment: furthermore any library problem would cause the output of the `print`s not to display