# Color Python output given #RRGGBB hex value

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

I've got a color from user in #RRGGBB hex format (`#D3D3D3` is light grey) and I'd like to color some output with it. I imagine I write `print("some text", color="#0000FF")` and get blue colored output. Is it possible (ideally without 3rd party software)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print colored output to the terminal in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340049/how-do-i-print-colored-output-to-the-terminal-in-python)

Comment: It depends. Truecolor ansi escapes are supported by some Unix/Linux terminal emulators. Where are you needing these?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm working on program that gets photo and prints it as ASCII art. Using Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following escape sequences on a *true-color aware terminal*:

- `ESC[ … 38;2;<r>;<g>;<b> … m` Select RGB foreground color
- `ESC[ … 48;2;<r>;<g>;<b> … m` Select RGB background color

Thus you can write a function:

```
RESET = '\033[0m'
def get_color_escape(r, g, b, background=False):
    return '\033[{};2;{};{};{}m'.format(48 if background else 38, r, g, b)
```

and use this like:

```
print(get_color_escape(255, 128, 0) 
      + get_color_escape(80, 30, 60, True)
      + 'Fancy colors!' 
      + RESET)
```

You can get doubled horizontal or vertical resolution by using for example `▀` and both background and foreground colour.

Comment: Not working for me, but it looks like I don't have _true-color aware terminal_ (LXTerminal). Will try it in somewhere else and then maybe accept answer. Btw. this is good test of your terminal: https://askubuntu.com/a/790991