# Coloured text in python with import os? (Windows, Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

To put it briefly, I'd like to change the colour of separate strings being printed, using anything that comes with Python 3 (no modules as it's for a school thing).

I got as far as changing the colour of everything being printed, using this:

```
import os
os.system("Color 01")
print("Blue")

os.system("Color 02")
print("Green")
```

However, that just uses the last colour referenced ("Color 02" = Green). Would there be a way I could use this to set colour as intended, or by using something else in python?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340049/how-do-i-print-colored-output-to-the-terminal-in-python/37340245#37340245) post has some alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that @atru

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print colored output to the terminal in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340049/how-do-i-print-colored-output-to-the-terminal-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can print colored text by specifying the ANSI escape sequence

```
import os
os.system("color")

COLOR = {
    "HEADER": "\033[95m",
    "BLUE": "\033[94m",
    "GREEN": "\033[92m",
    "RED": "\033[91m",
    "ENDC": "\033[0m",
}

print(COLOR["GREEN"], "Testing Green!!", COLOR["ENDC"])
```