# Python color output on terminal in linux is not working

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have linux server where I am running python script on server console my script colors are not displaying. Same script is working on Putty sessions.

I have checked echo $TERM in putty it is "xterm" and server console it is "linux".

```
OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
WARNING = '\033[93m'
FAIL = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'
BOLD = '\033[1m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output
from subprocess import call
import sys
import time
from shutil import copyfile
import commands
print OKGREEN + "Testing Green" + ENDC
```

I have also tried below setting up "os.system('export TERM="xterm"')" in python script but not working

Could some one help me to fix this issue.

Version: 2.7

Note: In same server console vim is displaying with colors

Comment: Not sure but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340049/how-do-i-print-colored-output-to-the-terminal-in-python/37340245#37340245) may help you.

Comment: @atru, Great below values are helped, RED   = "\033[1;31m"  
BLUE  = "\033[1;34m"
CYAN  = "\033[1;36m"
GREEN = "\033[0;32m"
RESET = "\033[0;0m"
BOLD    = "\033[;1m"
REVERSE = "\033[;7m"

Comment: So it fixed your problem? :)

Comment: Yes, Issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me with this code.

jay@Jay-Linux:~$ /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.15rc1

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Jay
class bcolors:
        HEADER = '\033[95m'
        OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
        OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
        WARNING = '\033[93m'
        FAIL = '\033[91m'
        ENDC = '\033[0m'
        BOLD = '\033[1m'
        UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
print bcolors.OKBLUE + 'OK', bcolors.ENDC
print bcolors.HEADER + 'This is header', bcolors.ENDC
print bcolors.FAIL + 'Failed.', bcolors.ENDC
print bcolors.OKGREEN + 'OK Green', bcolors.ENDC
print bcolors.WARNING + 'Warning', bcolors.ENDC
print bcolors.FAIL + 'Failed', bcolors.ENDC
```

[image: Output]