# Bold formatting in Python console

Tags: python, console, ansi-escape, output-formatting

I have defined a list in Python code.

```
list = ['kumar','satheesh','rajan']    
BOLD = '\033[1m'

for i, item in enumerate(list):
   list[i] = BOLD + item

print (list)
```

But I am getting the `output as ['\x1b[1mfsdfs', '\x1b[1mfsdfsd', '\x1b[1mgdfdf']`

But the required output is **`['kumar','satheesh','rajan']`**

How to `format` the `list elements` in `bold` using `python`?

Comment: Please consider using a different variable name for your list.. list is not an enforced keyword but it will give you unforeseeable problems if you use that as your variable name..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print colored/bold output to the terminal in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340049/how-do-i-print-colored-bold-output-to-the-terminal-in-python)

Comment: You are making the bold for square bracket also if it is really want print bold before printing the array

Answer (score 6):

You need to also specify `END = '\033[0m'`:

```
list = ['kumar','satheesh','rajan']

BOLD = '\033[1m'
END = '\033[0m'

for each in list:
    print('{}{}{}'.format(BOLD, each, END))
```

To make the list itself bold like **['kumar', 'satheesh', 'rajan']**:

```
print('{}{}{}'.format(BOLD, list, END))
```

Comment: Please close as duplicate [How do I print colored/bold output to the terminal in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340049/how-do-i-print-colored-bold-output-to-the-terminal-in-python)

Comment: I need the output to be enclosed in list. Inside the list only, the bold letters are not coming

Comment: Wow! It helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try printing as follows

```
for each in list:
    print(each)
```

following is the output
[image]

Comment: I did not downvote, and I know that it will work. But code only answers are considered as poor on SO. Explaining **why** it works that way will greatly improve your answer...

Comment: Your code will print all outputs in bold even if an item doesn't prefix with the escape string because it didn't ends with '\033[0m'.

Comment: I need the output to be enclosed in list. Inside the list only, the bold letters are not coming @Kalyan

Comment: are you trying to do it in ipython console?

Answer (score 0):

Kalyan gave a possible way, but failed to explain the why.

When ask Python to print a list, it will output the start and end of list markers(`[]`) and a *representation* of all the items of the list. For a string, it means that non printable characters will be escaped.

There is little you can do except printing separately the items

```
for i lst:
    print i
```

or build a unique string with join:

```
string_to_output = '[' + ', '.join(lst) + ']'
print(string_to_output)
```

By the way, as explained by Austin `'\x01b[1m` is an sequence to ask an ANSI compatible terminal to pass in bold mode, so you must at a time revert to normal mode with `'\x01b[0m`.

And remember: ANSI is common in Linux terminal emulations, but it is still far from being universal... Just try to use `export TERM=tvi950` before using it (and google for vt100 and tvi950 to understand more)...