# Print in terminal with colors using python but also want to save output in file but getting unreadable text

Tags: python

I tried terminal color code using python. But I also want to save it in a file but when I tried to that file is having unreadable text. How can I do this both?

```
BLACK, RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE = range(8)
def cprint(text, color=WHITE):
    seq = "\x1b[1;%dm" % (30+color) + text + "\x1b[0m"
    sys.stdout.write(seq)

cprint("String", RED)
```

It will get a red color output in the terminal.
But when I save it into a file it got with color code.

**Output in the file:**

```
 ^[[1;31mstring^[[0m
```

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print to console in color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265322/how-to-print-to-console-in-color)

Comment: @Hackaholic Read my question again understand the problem I am facing.

Comment: Why can't you write the unmodified text to the file?

Comment: In this case when you're printing on console then only apply color codes while writing in file only include string/text you want to log.

Comment: @MaheshKaria But the problem is both processes are in same way first it will print and save it to a log file.

Comment: So write a function that saves the plain text to the file and then saves the colored text to the console. Where is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append the text to a file every time you call the function

```
def cprint(text, file, color=WHITE):
    seq = "\x1b[1;%dm" % (30+color) + text + "\x1b[0m"
    sys.stdout.write(seq)
    with open(file, "a",) as f:
       f.write(text)

cprint("String", "/some/file", RED)
```