# How do I change the colour of output in C

Tags: c

FYI, I am using C NOT C++ in Xcode
 I can't use conio.h
I want to print text in different colour.
Any help is greatly appreciated 
Methods offered in other posts don't work which is why I have posted it again
Thanks

Comment: This question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219393/stdlib-and-colored-output-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Using escape code you can do this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLOR_RESET  "\x1b[0m"
#define COLOR_RED    "\x1b[31m"
#define COLOR_GREEN  "\x1b[32m"

int main()
{
    printf(COLOR_GREEN "Some good text\n");
    printf(COLOR_RED   "Some evil text\n");
    printf(COLOR_RESET "Some normal text\n");

    return 0;
}
```