# Are the escape sequences imported by ansicon nativly supported by Linux?

Tags: c, linux, windows, escaping, ansi-escape

For my final C project, we need to use Visual Studio and install something called Ansicon on our windows machine in order to get escape sequences to be able to program a game.

Unfortunately, I don't have Visual Studio at home, or Windows, so I would need to use a school computer to do this. I was reading that Ansicon should just install the escape characters that *NIX systems already support.

Will I be able to test my game without the functions that Ansicon provides?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219393 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

Comment: @ldrumm I was looking at the Wikipedia page before I posted this question, but I wanted to verify what I was reading.

Comment: Sorry, because wikipedia can be unreliable and I wanted to double check it's accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

After testing the following code

```
printf( "\033[2;1H");
printf( "\033[K");
```

It turns out that this is correct, and that my *NIX system does support escape characters out of the box.

Comment: It depends what terminal you're running it in. You're probably using something that's xterm compatible, and xterm supports some (but, I think not all) of ANSI. Likewise the Linux console and rxvt all support different subsets of the commands. So if your program behaves funny you could be running into this. You probably want to look into `screen`, which will emulate xterm/VT100/ANSI on top of another terminal, and should at least make things consistent.