# how to recognize string with color code with strncmp in c?

Tags: c, string, colors, strncmp

I have two programs in C:
a client and a server.

I'm not going to develop all the details of the code, things work fine. Except for this point:
I want my server to send **colored** acknowledgment messages and my client to identify them.

On the server the lines look like this:

```c
    //server side there there is:
    FILE * stream; // for the socket

    fprintf(stream,"\x1b[31m220\x1B[0m GET command received please type the file name\n");
    //here stream refers to a classic BSD socket which connect client to server
    //\x1b[31m colors text in red
    //\x1B[0m put back text color to normal
```

And I wonder what code should I use to detect the acknowledgment on the client:

```c
    //Client side there is:
    FILE * stream; // for the socket (client side)
    char buffer[100]; //to receive the server acknowledgment

    //fgets put the received stream text in the buffer:
    fgets (buffer , sizeof buffer, stream);
    
    //Here strncmp compares the buffer first 11 characters with the string "\x1b[31m220"
    if (strncmp (buffer, "\x1b[31m220",11)== 0)
    {
    printf("\x1B[48;5;%dmCommand received\x1B[0m%s\n",8,buffer);
    }
```

Things don't work. I wonder what should I put instead of `"\x1b[31m220",11` in the client to make things work. I suspect some characters of the color code to be interpreted and therefor to disappear from the string, but which ones?

---

There is an explanation of the color code here:
[stdlib and colored output in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219393/stdlib-and-colored-output-in-c)

Comment: `//Here strncmp compares the buffer first 11 characters` that's the problem, `\x1b` occupies only 1 character, it is an escape code, it should be 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"\x1b[31m220"` has **8 characters**, not 11. `strncmp` is going to fail at 9th character which is `'\0'` in this string and `'\x1B'` in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Make your life easier and let compiler calculate the sizes for you:

```
#define COLOURCODE "\x1b[31m220"

if (strncmp (buffer, COLOURCODE, sizeof(COLOURCODE) - 1)== 0)
```