# Change color of stdin in C (like in fish shell)

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to write a simple shell. I just want to change the color of the text the user types in which in the future will be used for stuff like syntax highlighting. Can I use the standard library for this or do I need to use something like ncurses. Its pretty easy to change the output color. Is there a similar solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can find this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219393/stdlib-and-colored-output-in-c

Comment: that question is for output. does it work the same way for imput

Comment: If i remember properly, you use the sequence to setup the color of the terminal. No mater input or output. So, if you setup the red color, if you do a scanf, the color should be red.

Comment: @Robert Thanks I'll try that. Do you know where I can find that?

Comment: Find what? The sequences to setup the color are listed in the link Robert posted.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry about that. I didn't read it carefully. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616906/how-do-i-output-coloured-text-to-a-linux-terminal).

I think this Sample Code should help you,

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("%s", "\033[92mEnter Number : \033[34m");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%s", "\033[0m");
    return 0;
}
```

Above coe will print `Enter number :`  in green and typing number in blue,

**Note : Make sure that your terminal supports ANSI escape color code [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling) for windows 10.**