# Why does system("Color B5") not work on replit?

Tags: c++, replit

I have the following code copied from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-print-colored-text-in-c/. I used the exact same code in replit and VS Code. The VS Code runs fine but in replit I get the following error message.

In the console:

[image: error message console]

In the shell:

[image: error message shell]

How can I get my text highlighted?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

// Driver Code
int main()
{
// B for background Color(Light Aqua)
// 5 for text color(Purple)
system("Color B5");
cout << "Geeks";

// 1 for background Color(Blue)
// 6 for text color(Yellow)
system("Color 16");
cout << " For ";

// D for background Color(Light Purple)
// E for text color(Light Yellow)
system("Color DE");
cout << "Geeks";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the shell, it's a warning saying you're not using the return value; you can ignore it there.

Answer (score 2):

`Color` is a `cmd.exe` built-in; it doesn't work anywhere but a DOS-like prompt (not even Powershell). `replit` is clearly running your program in `sh`, a shell for UNIX-like systems; it doesn't have the command. The guide you are reading is implicitly written solely for Windows systems; it won't work on UNIX-likes (e.g. Linux, BSD, macOS).

A *somewhat* more portable solution [uses ANSI color codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3219393/364696), which almost all modern terminals support (may not work in `cmd.exe` without [some](https://superuser.com/a/1050078) [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35864976/364696) though; it does work in the VSCode terminal), and doesn't require launching subprocesses for every single color change. If you want full portability, libraries exist, e.g. `ncurses`, which has been ported to Windows and provides complete terminal control support, independent of the actual OS, terminal and shell involved.