# C, how to change color of text with user input?

Tags: c, colors

In C language, there is this function

```
system("Color x")
```

Which changes the color of console text. However i've been wondering how to use this function with user input, by entering desired color, for example:

```
char color;
printf("Enter color: "); //user enters A/B/C etc.
scanf(" %c", &color);
system("Color %c", color);
```

Comment: Build a string to pass to system. `char cmd[42]; sprintf(cmd, "Color %c", color); system(cmd);`

Comment: I recommend looking into ANSI escape sequences. This approach is slow and windows-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) command doesn't accept parameters in the same way the [`print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) family of commands does (i.e. a format string followed by a variable argument list with variable names).
The solution is to build the desired string first using [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system). First, allocate memory for the target string:

```c
char cmd[8]; // E.g. "Color x" has 8 chars when including the null terminator.
```

Then, use `sprintf` to combine the format string and variable, and write the result to `cmd`:

```c
sprintf(cmd, "Color %c", color);
```

Finally, call `system` using the string just written to:

```c
system(cmd);
```

This is assuming that you want to use this method for changing colors. For a better approach, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219393/stdlib-and-colored-output-in-c).